# Duvida com operador

Tags: loop

[image: Duvida]

To resolvendo esse algoritmo simples quando me deparei com uma dúvida boba, ali na linha 4, aquele até significa `<` ou `<=` ?
No caso `for(k=4;k<7;k+=3)` ou for `(k=4;k<=7;k+=3)`?

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linha :

```
para k de 4 ate 7
```

É semelhante a

```
between 4 and 7
```

Ou seja, o numero tem que está dentro de uma determinada faixa de valores. que seria `4, 5, 6 e 7`

No caso em um `for(k=4; k<=7; ....`

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, avalie como resposta da pergunta.